# Retaining server connection in Android

Tags: android, singleton, client-server, android-context, orientation-changes

I'm currently facing some architecture problems of my Android application, and I have some troubles finding the "Android way" of solving these problems.

The application is solely a client to a web server. The application needs to be connected to the web server, which is can be done with several different protocols, which takes more than insignificant time to set up.

The application lets Android handle for example device rotations, and it is *NOT* okay for the application to reconnect to the server when rotating the device.

This is closely related to other similar problems in the app, so I want answer to some of my questions regaring this.

- Is a Singleton object retained after Orientation Changes? After switching from one activity to another? After multitasking away from the app to another? And for how long?
- Are objects stored in the Application class retained during an orientation change?
- If I have a service in my Android application (Lets say that it runs for 24/7), is the Application object alive 24/7 ? (I ask this question because I want to have the server connection singletons in the Application object.)
- Can you store your own objects in the Context or Application Context? What is the difference? Could this be used in some way for server connection? Or when is it supposed to be used?

Feel free to answer some or all of the questions! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is a Singleton object retained after Orientation Changes? After
>   switching from one activity to another? After multitasking away from
>   the app to another? And for how long?

Singleton object is retained in memory until its process is alive. And it can be killed when user shut down phone or open another application that consumes a lot of resources.
But singleton stays unchanged while configuration changes and activities switching. You can override your application class and create your singleton object there.

> Are objects stored in the Application class retained during an
>   orientation change?

No, application class is not retained on the whole lifecycle of the application.

> If I have a service in my Android application (Lets say that it runs
>   for 24/7), is the Application object alive 24/7 ? (I ask this question
>   because I want to have the server connection singletons in the
>   Application object.)

Services may also be restarted by a system when it needs more resources. But you can start service with [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) flag and it will be restarted by a system. But you can start service with [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) command and a chance that it will be restarted is almost zero. But in that way you need to show special notification while your service is running. For example, as a music application do.

> Can you store your own objects in the Context or Application Context?
>   What is the difference? Could this be used in some way for server
>   connection? Or when is it supposed to be used?

Sorry, I don't know that. Surely, you can store objects in your instance of Application class, but they will be also retained with an application.

I recommend you to use a service (I do that in my application). If is normally to your application to show notification about your connection your can surely use `startForeground()`. If not, you can start service as separate process (with `android:process` option in `AndroidManifest.xml`). But then you need to carefully send data between app and service. If both variants are not good for you - use a simple service. Applications with services have higher live priority.